# How to check Angular2 version with typescript

Tags: typescript, angular

I have written a simple app with angular2@2.0.0-alpha.11, and it works great. Now that I am testing it with the latest version of the alpha and beta avaible on npm, and I keep wondering if I really really changed or I am caching something.

I want to do something like the below on my root component

```
export class ChromeComponent {

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('angular version');
  }
}
```

`angular.version` on the console return `undefined`

Comment: A bug is open here to do that: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1357

Answer (score 49, accepted):

**Update since 4.0.0-rc.1**

Version is added for root selector in the DOM

[image]

Since angular2 version **2.3.0-rc.0** you can get version as follows:

```
import { VERSION } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent { 
  constructor() {
    console.log(VERSION.full); // print 2.3.0-rc.0
  }
}
```

Or you can just open browser console and check `body` tag
[image]

Comment: @gstackoverflow what do you mean `new angular2`?

Comment: core.umd.js:2834 EXCEPTION: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.html:6:4 caused by: Cannot read property 'full' of undefinedErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:2834(anonymous function) @

Comment: import { VERSION } from '@angular/core'; doesn't import something

Comment: to answer your question I need get answer to my question. Aim - to know my version. I don't know it.

Comment: my body in the DOM doesn't have version information and consol logging VERSION gives an error

Comment: The version shown by this method agrees with the ng --version in the folder, but the versions for the various parts of Angular in package.json are older.  It would be good to know why there is a difference.

Answer (score 11):

`ng -v` shows version of cli, node, os & angular.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that current angular 2 is beta 13 combined with a simple search : https://github.com/angular/angular/search?l=typescript&p=1&q=13&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93 and a look through docs https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/ means that its not exposed at runtime as a simple version number

Feel free to request it as a feature here : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues

Answer (score 0):

New answer since accepted one no longer the case on stable angular releases, easiest way to check angular version is to do so with npm list command at project root:

```
npm list  @angular/core
```

Just in case you can check following as well, versions should match:

```
npm list @angular/common

npm list @angular/compiler
```