# How to adapt angular 2 code to use URIs with parameters

Tags: javascript, angular

So far I've read https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#router-link and https://auth0.com/blog/2015/05/14/creating-your-first-real-world-angular-2-app-from-authentication-to-calling-an-api-and-everything-in-between/

but they're a bit too dense for my level and I'm getting lost easily.

So I thought about asking if there is a simpler way of doing what I want, or if there's another way of looking at the problem.

Currently I have "half" a webpage built

http://plnkr.co/edit/BcyPlw?p=preview

, in angular2, in which I use js and ts functions to get some D3 and some maps working:

```
<div layout="row" layout-wrap flex>
                      <div flex="50" *ngFor="#item of items">
                        <md-checkbox [checked]="exists(item, selected)" (click)="toggle(item, selected)">
                          {{ item }} <span *ngIf="exists(item, selected)">selected</span>
                        </md-checkbox>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

The idea now is to add URIs to events such as: if you click calendar, trigger an event so that I can return which cars were used in a given date, or which sessions does a car have in a given date, since I have created a webservice in java that is waiting to get something like:

```
@GET
@Path("/getData/{car}/{session}")
```

So the uri I am working with in the webservice (which I tested and works, and I want to connect with what I have in angular2 via tomcat) would be something like:

http://localhost:8080/Project/rest/projectName/getData/55/99

So I believe that is done with routing but 1º I haven't found examples that go deeper than /path (so, not /path/getData/data/data , in this case) , and 2º I am not really getting how to use what can be seen in the official tutorial `{ path: 'hero/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent }];`

It is quite confusing and as of right now I do not feel I have the level to do all those steps (and there are many that I don't need, either), it all seems too complex

Comment: So basically you want to route to a specific subroute, retreive data from a webservice for that route and display it?

Comment: 100% correct!! Right now I'm focusing on the specific subroute part, but that would the big picture, yes

Comment: Which version of Angular 2 and which version of the Angular 2 router do you sport at the moment?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check either of that and I just read here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36464281/6028947 that there is not an easy way to know, so, not sure. As for Route I am not using anything, I just started and first thing I saw was that they recently changed a lot of it, so, none so far, but the idea would be to use the last possible one

Comment: Well in your Plunker I saw you were using Angular 2 Beta.8 which is a pretty old version and meanwhile it has changed alot currently being at RC.3 (which also is the version you can see in the [current documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)). Since the new component router works a lot differently than in the old Beta versions and even older RC version, and has become easier to use, you might want to look into using a newer Angular version.

Comment: Allright I'll do that. When you say easier you talk about router component but that's what I've been reading and it doesn't quite look easy at all for non trivial cases, is there anyone that might have post a comprehensive guide or something? Not really sure how to face the problem tbh. Thanks for the answers btw!! I knew the plunker was getting outdated but didn't have the time till now (and didn't think it would be that old, but, learning new things!)

Comment: Really just read the [Router & Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) page. It's really well explained there, what steps you need to take, which files you need and all that.

Comment: I'll keep trying for sure, so far I got nothing that's all haha that's why I was asking. Btw since I have you here is there any "proper" way of upgrading libraries and whatever is necessary from .8 version to rc.3??

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.towfeek.se/2016/05/upgrading-to-angular-2-rc1-from-beta-lessons-learned/ But forget about the router mentioned in there because it changed completely again somehow, since they rewrote it with RC.3 :(