# Find out my Angular 2 application version and also the current official version of Angular 2

Tags: angularjs

I want to know my angular 2 version. But I am a bit confused. In my `package .json` file, I found this:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

I know I am using Angular 2.x for my application. I am more confused when I see Angular [version history](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). I though there where Angular 1.x and 2.x, but in this history there are so much versions. Can you please help me to know the current official angular version and also how to check the angular version of my application ?

Comment: go to `node_modules` -> `@angular` -> `core` -> `package.json`. Version is available there

Comment: *I know I am using Angular 2.x for my application* - you aren't. You're using 4.x (and `^4.0.0` is awful constraint). The first version that comes in changelog which is not beta or RC is the latest official. It's not clear what you're asking. And you shouldn't tag Angular 2+ questions with `angularjs`.

Comment: Try reading about SemVer: http://semver.org and https://nodesource.com/blog/semver-a-primer/

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456843/how-to-check-angular2-version-with-typescript

Answer (score 1):

> I know I am using Angular 2.x for my application.

Well, no, you are not. You're using Angular 4.x (that's what the `^` in front of the version number means).

Angular releases a major version every 6 month, and skipped version 3. So 4.0.0 is the first major version after 2.x. A major version is released every time a breaking change (even a very minor one) is introduced in the framework.

To find out which actual precise version you're using, check the version inside the file `node_modules/@angular/core/package.json`.

Comment: I am sorry I though there where angular 1.x and 2.x

Comment: is it really safe to build app in Angular, since it change so fast and break all.  Do you advise me to stay on angular 1.x or to build my application anyway with angular 4.x

Comment: It doesn't break all. Every six months, it release a new major version, precisely to send a clear signal that the release contains a breaking change. Nobody forces you to switch to that new major version, the breaking changes are documented, and the only new major version so far had very little breaking changes, that had no impact at all on most applications. Angular 1.x moved as fast in its early versions, and breaking changes happened basically at every release, and you couldn't know without reading the changelog.