# Angular2 equivalent for angular.version in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular

In the browser's developer console (press F12 to open it), typing the following 
"angular.version" will give the version of AngularJS APP loaded on page.

Is there an equivalent of it for Angular2.

Comment: There are several ways, already answered in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40904767/1121919

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check Angular2 version with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456843/how-to-check-angular2-version-with-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent console command, but you can use the following:

`getAllAngularRootElements()[0]['attributes'][1];`